# Java Swing Worker not stopping

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jlayer

I am building an application using Java swing. The application basically grabs police radio streams from Broadcastify website and plays them.

The application at the minute has two buttons: "Chicago Police", "Chicago Fire and EMS". When the Chicago Police button is pressed the Chicago Police stream starts to play. However, when the same button or a different button is pressed, the stream does not stop and they just play over themselves. I think it has something to do with the SwingWorker.

Basically, what i want it to do is play a stream and when another stream button is pressed, stop the current stream and then start the new one.

I have tried using the .cancel(true) method but this does not work.

Here is my code -

Frame class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class frame extends JFrame{

private JPanel north, south;
private JButton chicagoPolice, chicagoFireEms;
private JTextField status;
stream s = new stream();

public frame(){
    //set title
    super("Broadcastify Streams");

    //north panel
    north = new JPanel();
    north.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,250));
    north.setBackground(Color.RED);
    add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //Chicago Police button
    chicagoPolice = new JButton("Chicago Police");
    north.add(chicagoPolice);

    //Chicago Fire and EMS
    chicagoFireEms  = new JButton("Chicago Fire and EMS");
    north.add(chicagoFireEms);

    //south panel
    south = new JPanel();
    south.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //status bar
    status = new JTextField(15);
    status.setEditable(false);
    south.add(status, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //button action listeners
    chicagoPolice.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            s.setStream("http://relay.broadcastify.com:80/il_chicago_police2");
            s.playStream();
            status.setText("Playing - Chicago Police");
        }
    });

    chicagoFireEms.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            s.setStream("http://relay.broadcastify.com:80/836454979");
            s.playStream();
            status.setText("Playing - Chicago Fire and EMS");
        }
    });
}
}
```

stream class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class stream {

private SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker;
private String stream;
private Player player;

public stream(){
    stream = "";
}

public void setStream(String radioStream){
    stream = radioStream;
}

public void playStream(){

    worker = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>(){
        public Void doInBackground() throws Exception{

            URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(stream).openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            player = new Player(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            player.play();

            return null;
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}

}
```

main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame f = new frame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Can someone please put this into Eclipse and test it to see what i am talking about. You will also need the JLayer library found here: http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html

Thanks.

Comment: To help us now and to help yourself in the future, please edit your code and change your variable names to conform with Java naming conventions: class names all start with an upper-case letter and method/variable names with a lower-case letter. So your `stream` class should be something different, perhaps `PlayerStream` or some such. Does the Player class have a `cancel()` or `stop()` method?

Comment: And I would give each button its own PlayerStream object, and try to cancel the playing of any open PlayerStrean before trying to start my own new PlayerStream.

Comment: I have tried worker.cancel(true) method and player.close() methods and none of them seem to work.

Comment: No, you don't cancel the worker, you must call close() on the currently playing Player object. You should give your SwingWorker a method, say called `close()` that closes its currently playing Player.

Comment: I have tried that already and it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you're not doing it right, but "it does not work" tell us little. Show what you've tried and go into detail on how it's not working.

Comment: All the code is above can you please just put it into Eclipse and show me what you mean.

Comment: You've said that "I have tried that already", but I don't see that attempt. Please show what you mean by this. I have no idea what you could be doing wrong in this attempt, and thus am not sure how to help.

Comment: Yes i have already tried a lot of things that you have said. But there is some many different ways i have tried them, so i cannot put them all on here. I have tried using the two stop methods, i have tried making a new stream object with each button press.

Comment: All I'm asking is for your best good faith effort. Up to you and all depends on how much you need help.

Comment: Right instead of putting it in i will tell you what i have tried. I have tried stopping the worker when each button is pressed, and then starting it again. I have tried making a stream object with each button press, i have tried closing the player when the button is pressed and then start it up again.

Comment: When you call playStream, you're creating a new SwingWorker, but not stopping the last one. You need to tell the current SwimgWorkers Player to stop before starting the next one...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: been trying to tell him that for several minutes... to no avail.

Comment: I know, but i have already told you to no avail that i have attempted to stop the worker and it did not work.

Comment: **NO, you don't stop  the worker, you stop the currently running Player**. `</frustration>`

Comment: I have already attempted to stop the player and the worker and it did not work. How many times do i have to tell you </frustration>

Comment: @user3080860 Until you actually show use what you've tried...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, so I've read, but perhaps if a few more people say the same thing, we'll get the point across :P

Comment: I don't see `SwingWorker::cancel` anywhere in your code. Nor do I see where you're stopping the player. I don't even see where you're adding content to your `JFrame`, your main method just makes a 500x500 empty `JFrame`. How are we supposed to figure out what you've tried if you don't show us???

Comment: I add content to the JFrame is the frame class. What i did was put the code in without all of the methods i have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You must stop the Player, not the worker. Something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FooPlayer extends JPanel {
   private PlayerAction[] actions = {
         new PlayerAction(this, "Police",
               "http://relay.broadcastify.com:80/il_chicago_police2"),
         new PlayerAction(this, "Fire", "http://relay.broadcastify.com:80/836454979") };

   public FooPlayer() {
      for (PlayerAction action : actions) {
         add(new JButton(action));
      }
   }

   public PlayerAction[] getActions() {
      return actions;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      FooPlayer mainPanel = new FooPlayer();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FooPlayer");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class PlayerAction extends AbstractAction {
   private String path;
   private PlayerWorker playerWorker;
   private FooPlayer fooPlayer;

   public PlayerAction(FooPlayer fooPlayer, String name, String path) {
      super(name);
      this.path = path;
      this.fooPlayer = fooPlayer;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      for (PlayerAction action : fooPlayer.getActions()) {
         action.closePlayer();
      }

      try {
         URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(path).openConnection();
         playerWorker = new PlayerWorker(urlConnection);
         playerWorker.execute();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private void closePlayer() {
      if (playerWorker != null) {
         playerWorker.closePlayer();
      }
   }
}

class PlayerWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
   private Player player;

   public PlayerWorker(URLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException {
      urlConnection.connect();
      player = new Player(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      player.play();
      return null;
   }

   public void closePlayer() {
      if (player != null) {
         player.close();
      }
   }
}
```

The key thing being that the running Player must be stopped, not the SwingWorker, which will stop on its own, but the Player object that the SwingWorker is running.

Comment: Thank you. Finally we got there in the end.